# Unable to boot 12.10 AMD64 Live USB on GT5436E

Tags: installation, boot, live-usb

This is my hardware

http://support.gateway.com/s/PC/R/1009521/1009521sp3.shtml

I have refurbished the system with more RAM (3GB total now) and a new CPU(Core2Duo E2700 2x2.53Ghz)

When I try and boot the live USB of Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 I get the boot loader menu but when I press enter to boot from live USB, the system beeps and nothing happens. I can keep pressing enter but it just keeps beeping.

I have reflashed the BIOS to the most recent version for the chipset. Is there some option I haven't enabled perhaps? What could it be?

I am running 12.10 32bit with no issues.

Comment: Have you tried downloading again the ISO? Sometimes the image gets corrupt.

Comment: I checked the md5 it was spot on.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem in the `/syslinux/txt.cfg` of the bootkey.

Where it says `/casper/vmlinuz`, this has to be `/casper/vmlinux.efi`. Rename it, then you should be set.

Comment: I am going to check this asap, I will have access to the machine in question soon!