# 12.04.02 USB Installer, x86 works, x64 doesn't

Tags: 12.04, boot, system-installation, 64-bit, live-usb

so I downloaded both 32-bit and 64-bit flavors of 12.04.2 (MD5 checks out); don't want 12.10 since I prefer LTS. I used Universal USB Installer http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ to make a bootable USB.

32-bit: USB boots, can get to live desktop AND install, zero issues.

64-bit: USB boots, goes to menu (where I can choose between live desktop, install, memtest, etc). Live desktop and install do not work, it just makes a loud beep when I try to select (like the beep from POST) and does nothing (it stays at this menu). My laptop does indeed have a 64 bit CPU (I am trying to set up dual boot, my other OS is Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 x64, which is also a fresh re-install, if that matters). I also ran memtest earlier and there were no problems.

Help, please? What could be the issue? Am I stuck with just 32 bit?

Comment: What if you use another tool to make the LiveUSB like Unetbootin or Startup disk creator?.

Comment: Unetbootin did not work either. edit: I am OP, not sure how to make a comment... :/

Comment: This sounds identical to my problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/260503/unable-to-boot-12-10-amd64-live-usb-on-gt5436e

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot 12.10 AMD64 Live USB on GT5436E](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260503/unable-to-boot-12-10-amd64-live-usb-on-gt5436e)